# What's the proper way to use a lock guarded singleton between nested functions?

Tags: rust, locking, singleton, mutex

I have a arena singleton as following:

```rust
pub struct ComponentArena {
    components: HashMap<ComponentID, Component>,
    next_id: AtomicUsize,
}

impl ComponentArena {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        ComponentArena {
            components: HashMap::new(),
            next_id: 0.into(),
        }
    }

    pub fn instance() -> &'static Mutex<Self> {
        lazy_static! {
            static ref INSTANCE: Mutex<ComponentArena> = Mutex::new(ComponentArena::new());
        }
        &INSTANCE
    }

    pub fn add(&mut self, component: Component) -> usize {
        let id = self.next_id.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
        self.components.insert(id, component);
        id
    }

    pub fn get(&self, id: usize) -> Option<&Component> {
        self.components.get(&id)
    }

    pub fn get_mut(&mut self, id: usize) -> Option<&mut Component> {
        self.components.get_mut(&id)
    }
}
```

And here's how I use this singleton:

```rust
pub async fn walk_components<V>(component_ids: Vec<ComponentID>, visitor: V) -> Result<(), Error>
  where
    V: ComponentVisitor,
{
    let mut queue = VecDeque::new();

    queue.extend(component_ids);

    let arena = ComponentArena::instance().lock().unwrap();
    let mut futures = Vec::new();
    while let Some(comp_id) = queue.pop_front() {
        let comp = arena.get(comp_id).unwrap();
        let func = async move {comp.accept(visitor)};
        futures.push(func);
        
        for child_id in comp.children.iter() {
            queue.push_back(*child_id);
        }
    }

    match try_join_all(futures).await {
        Ok(_) => Ok(()),
        Err(err) => Err(err),
    }
}
```

The problem is that I want to get and use the components from the ComponentArena in the function call `comp.accept(visitor)`, which need to lock the arena again, but before the function `comp.accept(...)` is called, the ComponentArena instance is already locked and will be unlocked only when the function `walk_components` is returned. So I can't lock the ComponentArena again in the function `comp.accept(...)`(it calls the function `walk_components` recursively.

I'm a beginner in Rust and have no idea how to implement it. Hope someone can give me some suggestions.

I tried to unlock the instance manually, but I got an error:

use of unstable library feature 'mutex_unlock'

Comment: We can't really help you work around a limitation of `accept` without it's implementation so please provide a [mre].

Comment: It may work to add `accept` as a method on `ComponentArena` taking only the index. But more likely you want a proper arena implementation from crates.io

Comment: Nitpick: Avoid `lazy_static`. Use the standard library's [`OnceLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.OnceLock.html) or [`once_cell`'s `Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/unsync/struct.Lazy.html).

Comment: Why are you using atomic if you're only using it under a `&mut` reference? Use a simple integer.

Comment: Either pass the lock down to `accept()`, or use more fine-grained locks, or use a proper arena implementation such as [`typed-arena`](https://docs.rs/typed-arena).